# ansible delegate_to variable

Tags: variables, delegates, ansible, load-balancing

Hi I have below dynamic/static host group entry which has information about datacenter and environment

```
tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy
```

I need to use above group entry for `delegate_to` with two variables passed inline like below

```
- name: Copy Nginx Template
  template:
    src: nginx.conf.ctmpl.j2
    dest: "/var/consul/template/web.conf.ctmpl"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_{{ datacenter }}_{{ stage }}_gw_proxy"
```

But when when result was

```
failed: [172.16.16.136] (item=groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy) => {"item": "groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.16.16.136]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"_ansible_item_result": true, "item": "groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}]}
```

Which I assume Ansible is taking `groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy` as a host entry rather group entry.

Also tried with

```
delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['tag_Cluster_gateway_{{ datacenter }}_{{ stage }}_gw_proxy'] }}"
```

And result was

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.: 'dict object' has no attribute 
'tag_Cluster_gateway_{{ datacenter }}_{{ stage }}_gw_proxy'.
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can
 be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
fatal: [172.16.16.136]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}
```

But if I statically mention like `groups.tag_Cluster_gateway_use1_qa_gw_proxy` it works fine.

Hope I've provided enough details for the issue. Please help me on how to have variables passed with `deletage_to` for host group

Comment: delegate_to can only take single host and not the group. So the {{item}} in delegate_to line is a host ?

Comment: @Shasha99 {{ item }} is to loop over group of hosts. It works fine if I mention with making it a variable like I've configured. Problem is with variable even it shows it has processed it wont take as group

Comment: Ok, can you ssh manually to the host you are mentioning in delegate_to ? if yes then are you using passwords while connecting to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question was pretty long ago, so I assume it is not a problem anymore. If it still is, try the following:

```
delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
with_items: "groups['tag_Cluster_gateway_{{ datacenter }}_{{ stage }}_gw_proxy']"
```

The {{ }} brackets around the whole statement lets ansible search for the whole "tag_..._proxy" statement as variable. Ansible still seems to try to replace {{ item }} with the whole statement, which is why the error message states "'item' is undefined"